# signing pdf using itextsharp 5.4.4 - example

Tags: itext

Can someone supply an example or a link to an example that signs an existing pdf using itextsharp 5.4.4? Ideally keeping pdf/a conformity of the pdf? Thank you.

Edit: I understand the question looks as if I did not use google etc. BUT, new versions of itextsharp contain completely rewritten code for signing as well as other functions, making the existing examples non-functional. Also, itextsharp started using different names for methods eg. instead of createSignature one has CreateSignature, instead of getSignatureAppearance one seems to have SignatureAppearance etc. making the port from java examples a real nightmare. Also the samples in the source code itself are in java not c#. There is really nowhere else I can go.

Comment: Because SO is your personal google/yahoo/bing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures

The examples are in Java, but they were also ported to C#. You can find the C# examples [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/tutorial/signatures/). I didn't vote your question down, but... the first place to go when you have a question about iText should probably be http://itextpdf.com

The book I refer to (I'm the author) as well as the new examples are on the [learn page](http://itextpdf.com/learn).

Comment: Thank you, that helped. However, I suggest adding some comment to the site with the examples refering to the paper. I was able to get to the examples before through itextsharp site but I had no idea what they were referring to.

Comment: That's good advice, thanks! I'll forward it to the people who ported the examples.